# AfterSubmit and setting field value

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to update a field after a record is submitted but the field is not updating. I know the script is firing because the debug is showing the oldweight value. Can you not update a field in an AfterSubmit userevent.

```
// 2.0 - Fluent
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(["N/record"], function (r) {
    function onAfterSubmit(context) {
        var  oldweight = context.newRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'custbody93' });

            log.debug({
            title: 'Old Weight',
            details: oldweight
            });

        if (oldweight) {
            var fixWeight = context.newRecord;
            context.newRecord.setValue('custbody103', 'oldweight');
        };
    }  
   return {
        afterSubmit: onAfterSubmit
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `afterSubmit` event, the record has already been submitted and stored in the database, so you cannot update fields directly on the record in memory.

You'll need to use `N/record` to `load()` and `save()` the record or use `submitFields()` in order to update the database correctly.

Best practice for changing fields on the same record which triggered the User Event is to use `beforeSubmit` instead; within that entry point, your current code would work as you expect.

I have a video series on [understanding User Events](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLG2tK6Va2WUCseA3viGC2oYPkyA45wfA-) and one on how to [work with records](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2glMd0y47M) on my [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/StoicSoftware/).